# next / previous pagination query with parameters php mysql with parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem: here is the structure of my tables [image]

[image]

and here is my code:

```
            $SQL_NEXT_PROJECT_ID ="SELECT id  FROM projects WHERE id < '".$id_project."' and project_types_id='".$project_type_id."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
            $conn->query($SQL_NEXT_PROJECT_ID);
            foreach ($conn->query($SQL_NEXT_PROJECT_ID) as $rowProjectNext) {
                $next_project_id = $rowProjectNext['id'];
            }

            $SQL_PREVIOUS_PROJECT_ID ="SELECT id  FROM projects WHERE id > '".$id_project."' and project_types_id='".$project_type_id."' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
            $conn->query($SQL_PREVIOUS_PROJECT_ID);
            foreach ($conn->query($SQL_PREVIOUS_PROJECT_ID) as $rowProjectPrevious) {
                $previous_project_id = $rowProjectPrevious['id'];
            }
```

the thing is that i need to put the query with an aditional condition from the 'images' table i have to evaluate the main field ='1', i have been trying to do it with a inner join but it doesnt seem to work, here i attach the query that i have been trying

```
$SQL_NEXT_PROJECT_ID ="SELECT projects.id  FROM projects INNER JOIN images WHERE projects.id > '".$id_project."' and project_types_id='1' and main='1' ORDER BY projects.id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Basically what i need to do is to create next / previous links to projects of certain type (project_types_id) based on the current id of the project ($id_project) taking into consideration the fact that the project should have a image that has the main field equal to '1'

hope i explained myself well...

Answer (score 0):

Well youre not joining on anything... you need an `ON` clause.

```
SELECT pr.id  FROM projects pr 
INNER JOIN images img ON (pr.id = img.projects_id AND img.main = 1)
WHERE pr.id > ? 
AND pr.project_types_id = 1 
ORDER BY pr.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end i did it like this

```
$_nextPrevious = array();

            $SQL_SEARCH_VALUES="SELECT images.projects_id AS projectId FROM projects INNER JOIN images ON ( projects.id = images.projects_id ) AND project_types_id =  '".$project_type_id."' AND images.main =  '1' LIMIT 0 , 30";
            $conn->query($SQL_SEARCH_VALUES);
            foreach($conn->query($SQL_SEARCH_VALUES) as $rowNextPrevious) {
                $value = $rowNextPrevious['projectId'];                    
                array_push($_nextPrevious, $value);
            }


            $currentValue = array_search($id_project, $_nextPrevious);

            $next = $currentValue + 1;

            $previous = $currentValue - 1;

            $next_project_id = $_nextPrevious[$next];

            $previous_project_id = $_nextPrevious[$previous];

            return array($project_name,$project_description,$project_path, $_images, $next_project_id, $previous_project_id);
```

using an array instead of two searches...